# How to wrap Coordinator Layout in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinator-layout

I´m attempting to use the new Android Design Library´s CoordinatorLayout inside of another layout. The CoordinatorLayout contains a RecyclerView. What I´m attempting to do is to place a simple LinearLayout below the CoordinatorLayout. This layout should be placed below the CoordinatorLayout. This is XML I´m using:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/conversation_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_36dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I´m attempting to wrap the CoordinatorLayout inside another LinearLayout. However, on-screen the second part of the layout doesn´t even render.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because the `CoordinatorLayout` has `layout_height="match_parent"`. That means it takes the whole size of the screen and your `LinearLayout` *is* rendered but it is below the `CoordinatorLayout` and off-screen.

An easy way to fix this would be setting the `weight` of the `CoordinatorLayout` to fill the parent layout but leave space necesseary to display the footer `LinearLayout`. This would be

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

But this is not ideal way so I would suggest leaving the `CoordinatorLayout` as the root element and place your `LinearLayout` just bellow the `RecyclerView` where it belongs. Since your footer `LinearLayout` has fixed height this can be done easily

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:paddingBottom="150dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <EditText />
        <ImageButton />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up doing as well. I put in a fixed padding at the bottom. However, I´m weary as to how this will look on lower-resolution screens.

Comment: The `dp` unit is well designed and will mostly work OK. In case it didn't you can always specify different [dimensions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) for different screen sizes.

Comment: I am using this code with the exception that instead of `RecyclerView` i have a `FrameLayout` which is replace with `Fragments` at runtime by the activity. The fragments have NestedScrollView, RecyclerView etc in them. 

But in my case the `LinearLayout` (`Bottom Footer`) sits right below the appbar and not the end of the screen. I have tried `layout_gravity & `layout_anchor` but it sticks to the bottom of the app_bar

Comment: Do you use weight or fixed height?